# as.POSIXct isn't interpreting the date 19/10/2008

Tags: r, datetime, formatting, posixct

Ok, this is weird... I have a colum full of dates, but when I did the analysis in `ggplot2`, it kept giving me a warnign:

> Warning messages:
> 1: Removed 1 row(s) containing missing values (geom_path).
> 2: Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_point).

When I went looking, the date `19/10/2008` was replaced by `NA` when I did `as.POSIXct()`. WHen I isolate, I get the same result:

```
> as.POSIXct("19/10/2008", format = "%d/%m/%Y")
[1] NA
```

However, the same doesn't happen for `19/10/2009` or `19/05/2008` or `18/10/2008` or `20/10/2008`, and probably many others. Actually, I haven't found a date that has the same property... Why is this happening? And how can I fix it? Is it even fixeable?

EDIT: I don't know what this does, but I was asked to add this:

```
> Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME")
[1] "en_US.UTF-8"
> Sys.timezone()
[1] "America/Sao_Paulo"
```

Comment: Please add the outputs of `Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME")`  and `Sys.timezone()` to your question.

Comment: Done. Why is this necessary?

Comment: As usual, the issue is DST. That date is the start of DST in Brazil. Since you implicitly specify 00:00:00 and that time didn't exist due to the time change, you get `NA`.

Comment: I don't understand... Why does this only happen for this specific date?

Comment: It should happen for all dates listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time_in_Brazil) as DST start.

Comment: Anyway, why are you using `as.POSIXct` and not `as.Date`?

Comment: ...because I don't know that function. Let me guess: same thing, no time (which are causing the problem). Am I close?

Comment: Yeah, `as.Date()` worked. Thanks!

Comment: `as.POSIXct` creates a date-time object. `as.Date` creates a date object.